# How do i create a Dynamic Dropdown Data Validation List based on pre selected criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, dropdownlist

I seldom use Google Sheets or Excel, but now that I'm working on a card game, I have since thrusted myself into formulas and data validation.

I'm currently running into a logic issue.

I would like to make a dynamic dropdown of column C in the abilities sheet within the Card Database Sheet.

It will dynamically change based on the character type in the Card Database Sheet

Sheet for the abilities:
[image: Sheet for the abilities]

Sheet for the Card Database and Dropdown:
[image]

If anyone were able to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem you are facing

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The problem that i am facing is that i cannot seem to find a formula that i can put into the data validation tool that will get me only the cells that contain the criteria im looking for. 

so for instance in the Card DataBase Sheet I can use the drop down on B2 to select, entity, character, city or survivor.

when I make that selection what i would like is for L2 be give me a dropdown list of card abilities descriptions that is specific to Character and Any.}

If I change B2 to entity, it should give me a dropdown list containing ability descriptions that are Entity and any

Comment: That is not the problem, that is the task you want to accomplish. The problem is where you are stuck after having tried something. Look into cascading drop down list.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Oh sorry,  so yes I've tried a number of formulas including, Index/Match, VLOOKUP, Indirect, and some more complication variations of these to try and place into the data validation sheet but I would just errors of the data not being a range. 

Cascading dropdown I have looked into but was concerned with changing the layout of the table as well as not being able to have dependent list not changing based what is in the Card Database Sheet instead of the Abilities Sheet.

Comment: it may not seem like i did anything but that is because im coming to you after trying a ton of formulas cleaning up and searching for help.

Comment: I forgot to mention what i am trying to do at the end of all this is do a data merge in illustrator or InDesign so having that first database remain clean my goal

Comment: Do you want to create the dependent drop down list? https://exceljet.net/dependent-dropdown-lists

Answer (score -1):

It seems I was being a bit scared in how to approach this and have found these two links to best help me thanks @cybernetic.nomad for the assistance.

What i needed to do was create a dependent drop down list using Horizontal Data structure instead of a singular column data list. it seems counter intuitive but it helps with creating data validation where each row uses a duplicate horizontal list of its data that is maintained and updated using the original single column list.

This link goes over the initial ways of creating dependant dropdown lists with both ways to laying out data.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGIb6mVvEMY

this goes over how to create multiple dependent dropdowns as the first one was tied to only 1 cell and couldn't be dropped down per cell. this goes over how to make the defendant list cover a range of cells in a singular column.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mo4COng7Sg

Comment: Please [edit] your answer ad describe the contents of your links/videos, and what the solution actually is, otherwise this is a link only answer and should the video(s) be deleted, then the answer will not be very helpful...

Comment: Please consider mentioning the word "excel" in the title of your post. Your post would gain more visibility with the excel specialists here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).